# Should I create mapper objects or use the declarative syntax in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

There are two (three, but I'm not counting [Elixir](http://elixir.ematia.de/trac/wiki), as its not "official") ways to define a persisting object with [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org):

#### [Explicit syntax for mapper objects](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapping_styles.html#classical-mappings)

```
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, String, MetaData, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapper

metadata = MetaData()

users_table = Table('users', metadata,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('name', String),
)

class User(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __repr__(self):
       return "<User('%s')>" % (self.name)

mapper(User, users_table) # &lt;Mapper at 0x...; User&gt;
```

#### [Declarative syntax](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapping_styles.html#declarative-mapping)

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base()

class User(Base):
     __tablename__ = 'users'
     id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
     name = Column(String)

     def __init__(self, name):
         self.name = name

     def __repr__(self):
         return "<User('%s')>" % (self.name)
```

I can see that while using the mapper objects, I separate completely the ORM definition from the business logic, while using the declarative syntax, whenever I modify the business logic class, I can edit right there the database class (which ideally should be edited little).

What I'm not completely sure, is which approach is more maintainable for a business application?

I haven't been able to find a comparative between the two mapping methods, to be able to decide which one is a better fit for my project.

I'm leaning towards using the "normal" way (i.e. not the declarative extension) as it allows me to "hide", and keep out of the business view all the ORM logic, but I'd like to hear compelling arguments for both approaches.

Answer (score 26):

"What I'm not completely sure, is which approach is more maintainable for a business application?"

Can't be answered in general.

However, consider this.

The Django ORM is strictly declarative -- and people like that.

SQLAlchemy does several things, not all of which are relevant to all problems.

1. SQLAlchemy creates DB-specific SQL from general purpose Python.  If you want to mess with the SQL, or map Python classes to existing tables, then you have to use explicit mappings, because your focus is on the SQL, not the business objects and the ORM.
2. SQLAlchemy can use declarative style (like Django) to create everything for you.  If you want this, then you are giving up explicitly writing table definitions and explicitly messing with the SQL.
3. Elixir is an alternative to save you having to look at SQL.

The fundamental question is "Do you want to see and touch the SQL?"

If you think that touching the SQL makes things more "maintainable", then you have to use explicit mappings.

If you think that concealing the SQL makes things more "maintainable", then you have to use declarative style.

- If you think Elixir might diverge from SQLAlchemy, or fail to live up to it's promise in some way, then don't use it.
- If you think Elixir will help you, then use it.

Comment: Wow, this answer really helped me decide.

Answer (score 16):

In our team we settled on declarative syntax.

Rationale:

- `metadata` is trivial to get to, if needed: `User.metadata`.
- Your `User` class, by virtue of subclassing `Base`, has a nice ctor that takes kwargs for all fields. Useful for testing and otherwise. E.g.: `user=User(name='doe', password='42')`. So no need to write a ctor!
- If you add an attribute/column, you only need to do it once. "Don't Repeat Yourself" is a nice principle.

Regarding "keeping out ORM from business view": in reality your `User` class, defined in a "normal" way, gets seriously monkey-patched by SA when `mapper` function has its way with it. IMHO, declarative way is more honest because it screams: "this class is used in ORM scenarios, and may not be treated just as you would treat your simple non-ORM objects".

Comment: You still have to repeat yourself (at `__init__` and ORM), but of course its easier to not mess everything when its in the same class. For now I'm going explicit, but I'm keeping an eye at the declarative syntax. Will have to take it out for a spin in some side project. For legacy db, well, I pretty much *have to* go with explicit. I'm thinking about what fancy stuff I could do with the unittests, one way or the other ;)

Comment: @voyager When you inherit from `Base`, you don't need to write `__init__` at all, you get a nice already provided by `Base`.

Comment: @PavelRepin (it's been 10 years :) but...) how did you test without being depended on your DB? Or did you use in-memory SQLite for this purpose? Or something else?

Answer (score 6):

I've found that using mapper objects are much simpler then declarative syntax if you use [sqlalchemy-migrate](http://packages.python.org/sqlalchemy-migrate/) to version your database schema (and this is a must-have for a business application from my point of view). If you are using mapper objects you can simply copy/paste your table declarations to migration versions, and use simple api to modify tables in the database. Declarative syntax makes this harder because you have to filter away all helper functions from your class definitions after copying them to the migration version.

Also, it seems to me that complex relations between tables are expressed more clearly with mapper objects syntax, but this may be subjective.

Comment: One benefit of declarative syntax with sqlalchemy-migrate is that your migrations can use business logic directly.  Many migrations are trivial column adds and renames, but if you are doing major data manipulations as a result of a schema change it is very nice to have the business logic available to help keep everything consistent.

Comment: @Kekoa sounds nice in some scenarios, but also sounds fragile. That business logic has another responsibility and it might change in a way that breaks the migration. iMHO migrations should not depend on production business-logic, rather be self-contained.

Answer (score 3):

as of current (2019), many years later, sqlalchemy v1.3 allows a hybrid approach with the best of both worlds

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/declarative/table_config.html#using-a-hybrid-approach-with-table

```
metadata = MetaData()

users_table = Table('users', metadata,
  Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
  Column('name', String),
)

# possibly in a different file/place the orm-declaration
Base = declarative_base(metadata)

class User(Base):
  __table__ = Base.metadata.tables['users']
  def __str__(): 
    return "<User('%s')>" % (self.name)
```