# How does Session tracks changes in sqlalchemy?

Tags: sqlalchemy

I studied for a while the sqlalchemy library. Besides its usefulness, I find this library very educational, as it covers pythonic ways of implementing things (like the instrumentation via descriptors) and its overall architecture.

Yet, there are some principles that I would like clarification about.

The concept of `InstanceState` and its connection to the `Session` object:
I looked in an [article](https://www.aosabook.org/en/sqlalchemy.html) that explains the architecture of the library, for understanding the idea of `InstanceState` and tracking changes of objects, but I would still like an explanation:
Each instance of instrumented class has an `InstanceState` object in it (the `_sa_instance_state` attribute) as in the chart from the article above:
[Session overview chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lr3VP.png)

Yet, how does it really track the changes of the object?
When the `Session` flushes the changes to the db, does it actually implement the changes that are tracked and found inside the `InstanceState`? (Is it like the `Session` perform iteration over all of the objects in his identity map and checks which one has changes in his `InstanceState`, or when chaning objects the `InstanceState` itself of an object notifies the `Session` that some changes occured to this object?)

And when does the `Mapper` actually enter the picture? It saves the correlation between the class attributes and the table columns, so when a change is taking place on an object, does the `InstanceState` is using the `mapper` to log what changes are really needed to be performed in the db?
Or is it other part of the ORM system that actually uses it? as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9544495) simulates the `Mapper` to obesever in the subject-observer pattern:

> Think of instrumentation as transparently adding a "Subject" implementation to a mapped class for the "Observer" mapper in a subject-observer pattern.

Comment: "Is it like the Session perform iteration over all of the objects in his identity map and checks which one has changes" — no, it keeps sets of new / dirty / etc. objects: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Session.dirty